# Creating AVD for simulation with customized resolution does not have any buttons to navigate

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I try to define couple of AVDs to simulate my app on different screen sizes, but when I set the

`Skin -> Resolution` instead of `build-In` I always just get a screen **without** navigation buttons like "Menu" or "<-".

As soon as I chose

> Skin -> Build-In

I have on the right side all the buttons I need.

What do I have to do to get these buttons when I chose "Resolution" and type in my 320 x 480 ?

I also tried to add in the

> Hardware

section KeyboardSupport , Hardware back and homekey - but it all does not make any difference.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The buttons come from skins, you would have to create a custom one. However, you don't need the buttons, you can use your computer's keyboard to call the menu, etc:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html

Comment: super - that's even easier - I read on this page - however not the part about the keys :) Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, much easier. I really don't like the skins, to be quite honest.